# Node-Red receiving response as JSON

Tags: python, node.js, node-red

This is my flow in Node-Red

[image]

I'm simply injecting a string into a tcp node to my server, then my server returns the value as a string. However, I keep getting JSON response from Node-Red like the following `{"hello":""} where the value is empty and key is hello`.

Code:

```
while True:
        #Receiving from client
        data = conn.recv(4096)
        all_data += data
        print 'Received Message : ' + all_data
        if not data:
                print 'Final Received Message : ' + all_data
                headers = {'Content-Type','text/plain'}
                req = urllib2.Request('<my server link>', headers)
                try:
                        urllib2.urlopen(req, str(all_data))
                except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
                        print "error posting the request " + error.reason

                break
```

UPDATE:
Even though in my code I'm returning a string, I keep receiving a JSON response in Node-Red instead(check the debug result above), any idea why?

Comment: You've not actually asked a question here

Comment: What version of Node-RED are you using? Testing v0.13.2 and curl I get the expected plain text payload. (p.s. add a http-out node so Node-RED actually responds with 200 for the post)

Comment: BTW - I also answered this where you asked it over here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/254167/node-red-responding-with-json-instead-of-string.html#answer-254168

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the python, it should be like this:

```
while True:
    #Receiving from client
    data = conn.recv(4096)
    all_data += data
    print 'Received Message : ' + all_data
    if not data:
        print 'Final Received Message : ' + all_data
        headers = {'Content-Type':'text/plain'}
        req = urllib2.Request('<my server link>', None, headers)
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(req, str(all_data))
        except urllib2.HTTPError, error:
            print "error posting the request " + error.reason
        break
```

- The first change was to swap the ',' for a ':' in the headers
- Second was to add the `None` between the URL and the headers in the Request line.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't know how and why I wrote it with a comma. Spent ours to debug where the problem were in front of my eyes. I'll mark correct there as well.